# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libpff

Tags: python

I tried many times to install the module libpff,  but I receive this error:

" Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libpff (from versions: none)"

Is there any ideas to fix it?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56596752/pip-randomly-fails-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-wit) help?

Comment: How did you try to install it exactly?

Comment: what have you tried so far please ?